# How to get a return value from QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Tags: c++, qt

I am calling from my thread the following:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(pProcessor,
                          "doTask",
                          Qt::QueuedConnection,
                          Q_RETURN_ARG(quint32, taskId),
                          Q_ARG(quint64,   objId),
                          Q_ARG(quint8,    intId),
                          Q_ARG(QString,   name),
                          Q_ARG(QString,   comment)
                          );
```

but it just fails, no matter what I do. If I take out Q_RETURN_ARG(quint32, taskId), the method is invoked, but I need the taskId, which I cannot get.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to call a method of an object from non owner thread & wants to get the return value. In order to do that use "Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection" as a connection type.

```
quint32 taskId; // Declare taskId.
qRegisterMetaType<quint32>("quint32");
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(pProcessor,
                      "doTask",
                      Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                      Q_RETURN_ARG(quint32, taskId),
                      Q_ARG(quint64,   objId),
                      Q_ARG(quint8,    intId),
                      Q_ARG(QString,   name),
                      Q_ARG(QString,   comment)
                      );
```

Incase your method returns non standard return type you have to register your type before calling **QMetaObject::invokeMethod(...)**. Refer http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for invokeMethod states that

> The return value of the member function call is placed in *ret*. If the
>   invocation is asynchronous, the return value cannot be evaluated.

I guess this happens because the code below this function call is continued to be executed, while your `doTask` method may not yet be called. Try using `Qt::DirectConnection` therefore.

Answer (score 0):

from docs: `If the invocation is asynchronous, the return value cannot be evaluated`.

Then you should switch to Qt::DirectConnection, or change your design. [QFuture](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfuture.html), of course, could help.

I blogged [here](http://prolog-in-the-wild.blogspot.it/2013/07/a-trick-for-qt-interthread-communication.html?view=sidebar) about a different solution, using C++ lambda facility to issue calls from background threads to GUI thread (see the text after 'My Solution' label).